# Set up WebApp to use primary Django app in subdirectory

Tags: django, azure

I have continuous deployment set up with a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ProgBot/AWScoutingDev), and I would like this to replace the default Django app. However, all of the apps for the new are in the directory of the Django project (that is, the folder/module with the settings.py I want to be used is in a directory that should not be treated as a module), so how could I set the settings module in one of these apps to be the one that should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I just needed to add the directory the apps are contained in to the PYTHONPATH specified in the web.config (and, in my case, load a newer version of Django)